# How to convert a MemoryStream with multiple datatypes over a redis server

Tags: c#, ubuntu, redis

I am trying to submit information across a redis server, I am creating a console app with C# in VS and am using a MemoryStream that consists of a Long, String, Int, and Double. On a VM running ubuntu, I am using MonoDevelop to read the info I write from VS's MemoryStream

I am fairly new to transferring data across a server, so far I have made an attempt by converting my MemoryStream into a byte array and then from that byte array to a String, because redis only accepts String data, and then I am trying to convert it back into the original stream on my other console on the Ubuntu VM.

```
public void SaveBigData()
{
    var cache = RedisConnectorHelper.Connection.GetDatabase();
    long timeStamp = shortTime;
    String name = "Bob";
    int number = rnd.Next(100);
    double price = rnd.Next(20) + rnd.NextDouble();           

    binWriter.Write(timeStamp);
    binWriter.Write(name);
    binWriter.Write(number);
    binWriter.Write(price);
    binWriter.Flush();

    var testData = dataStream.ToArray();
    var value = Convert.ToBase64String(testData);
    Console.WriteLine($"Convert.ToBase64String={value}");
    cache.StringSet($"Device_Status:{numOfEntries++}", value);

}
private static int numOfEntries = 0;        
private static MemoryStream dataStream = new MemoryStream();
private static BinaryWriter binWriter = new BinaryWriter(dataStream);
```

When reading the data on my VM my method looks like this:

```
public void ReadData()
    {
        var cache = RedisConnectorHelper.Connection.GetDatabase();
        var devicesCount = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < devicesCount; i++)
        {
            var value = cache.StringGet($"Device_Status:{i}");
            var redisString = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
            dataStream = new MemoryStream(redisString);
            var testPrinter = dataStream.toString();
            Console.WriteLine($"Value={value}");
            Console.WriteLine($"redisString={redisString}");
            Console.WriteLine($"testPrinter={testPrinter}");
        }
    }
```

This is as far as I have gotten, and I am unsure how to get the original information in the same dataTypes but also be able to assign values on the VM with the retrieved values.

Comment: You're describing _serialisation_ - I think knowing that term will help you find more information - there's a lot of ways to do it.

Comment: "because redis only accepts String data" - that is entirely incorrect; redis is binary safe; you can store anything in redis without it having to be text or even text-ish. I routinely store blobs that are gzip compressed protobuf data; not even remotely textish; is it possible that you're using a *really really old client library* that pre-dates RESP ?

Comment: I just noticed the use of `StringSet` and `StringGet` - that sounds suspiciously like SE.Redis, in which case: the value there is a `RedisValue`, which can take *many things* - sure it'll take a `string`, but it will also take a `byte[]` (and a ton of other things)

Comment: Thank you for all your help -James, I am looking up serialization and that does very much sound like what I am trying to do. -Marc, I found some information and have just started working with redis, the only way I could get data to my server was with `StringSet` but how would I store all of my data to a `RedisValue` with a `byte[]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is, as James Thorpe notes: serialization. Now, you *can* do this manually, but frankly it isn't a good use of your time. If you *want* text data, you should probably just look into using Json.NET. Since the question makes a lot of noise about binary, for things like that you *probably* want to use something like protobuf. Fortunately, protobuf-net exists and works well here; example:

```
// store
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    var obj = new MyData
    {
        Name = name,
        Price = price,
        Number = number,
        TimeStamp = timeStamp,
    };
    Serializer.Serialize<MyData>(ms, obj);
    // older versions: cache.StringSet("somekey", (byte[])ms.ToArray());
    cache.StringSet("somekey", RedisValue.CreateFrom(ms));
}
// retreive
using (var ms = new MemoryStream((byte[])cache.StringGet("somekey")))
{
    var obj = Serializer.Deserialize<MyData>(ms);
    Console.WriteLine(obj.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(obj.Price);
    Console.WriteLine(obj.Number);
    Console.WriteLine(obj.TimeStamp);
}
```

with:

```cs
[ProtoContract]
public class MyData
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public long TimeStamp { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public double Price { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(4, DataFormat = DataFormat.ZigZag)]
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

protobuf-net and SE.Redis work well together - they have the same author.